# How to pass the data from javascript to Web API Controller using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am not to pass a data from javascript to Web API Controller using ajax, I don't  how to create Web API with fields
Please Share Your Experience and help me out from this problem

Share me some pdf or notes which you have

This is my Ajax code:

```
    type: "POST",
    url: "api/WebApiPra/",
    contentType: "application/json",
    datatype: "text",
    data:JSON.stringify(
        {
        EmpName: a,
        EmpDOB: b,
        EmpAge: c,
        EmpGender: d,
        EmpMartial: e,
        EmpBlood: f,
        EmpPhone: g,
        EmpEmgPhone: h,
        EmpAddress: i,
        EmpEmail: j
    }),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

This is my controller

```
  [WebMethod]
    [HttpPost]
    public void emplcrea([FromBody]EmployDetail e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Any reason that you need to use `JSON.stringify` here?

Comment: no i  searched on internet help me

Comment: Remove `JSON.stringify` as jQuery does it for you when you set the `contentType`. Have you checked the response to the request in the console?

Comment: Can you tell me how the web api function should be for this ajax? @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Not with the information you've provided, as it should work correctly as it is. Hence why I mentioned to check the console to find the exact response from the request and diagnose any errors

Comment: i dont know how to check it on console @Rory McCrossan

Comment: Unfortunately SO is not a place for tutorials. You can readily find full documentation, step by step tutorials and samples at the [ASP.Net site](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNET-Web-API-JavaScript-d0d64dd7)

Answer (score 0):

maybe try it ?

```
    yourData = {
        EmpName: a,
        EmpDOB: b,
        EmpAge: c,
        EmpGender: d,
        EmpMartial: e,
        EmpBlood: f,
        EmpPhone: g,
        EmpEmgPhone: h,
        EmpAddress: i,
        EmpEmail: j
    };
```

then

```
   type: "POST",
    url: "api/WebApiPra/",
    contentType: "application/json",
    data:JSON.stringify(yourData),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how API function created for this ajax

Comment: sorry.. i don't know how to do API use asp.net,  if yoy mean that .